# How to launch an EC2 instance without key pair via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I would like to launch an EC2 instance without key pair with my Terraform configuration. I could not find any info on internet which indicates usage of "no keypair" in Terraform. Anyone who have configured Terraform to be used this way?

Comment: Just don't provide the `key_name` parameter? What have you tried? Can you edit your question to show the Terraform code you've written and explain what issues you're having with it?

Comment: This is the solution for my issue. I've tried to run my EC2 instance terraform code without key-pair parameter and it launched the instance without key-pair. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's Terraform script that makes an EC2 instance of type `t2.micro` without a key and output its IP address.

terraform.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

variable "instance_type" {
 default = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
 ami = "ami-0d1cd67c26f5fca19"
 instance_type = "var.instance_type"
}

output "ip" {
 value = "aws_instance.ec2_instance.public_ip"
}
```

Put it on a dir and run it by using this command `terraform apply`.
You can use `terraform plan` for testing it.

> Note: Don't forget to add your `access_key` and `secret_key` to your local aws configuration (`aws configure`) in order for it to work. You can also use [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) to avoid mistakenly exposing your credentials.

Comment: "Note: Don't forget to add your `access_key` and `secret_key` to the file". That is an easy way to accidentally expose your credentials by committing them to version control. It would be preferable to set up credentials with AWS CLI's `aws configure` command or use a tool like aws-vault to safely get temporary credentials. https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault